# Replace all characters before @

Tags: regex, ruby

I have a string `'test@gmail.com'`

I want to use regex for replace all characters before @ to star(*)

So expected result:
`'****@gmail.com'`

I tried to use a regexp like this:
`'test@gmail.com'.gsub(/^.*?(?=@)/, '*')` but the result is `*@gmail.com`

or regexp like this:
`'test@gmail.com'.gsub(/^[^@]*/, '*')` but result is the same `*@gmail.com`

I don't want to use the `.split` method

May you give some advice please?

Comment: You can count the amount of characters the match has, and use those amount of `*` in the replacement.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use

```rb
'test@gmail.com'.gsub(/.(?=.*@)/, '*')
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/GUJ0uu/1) and the [Ruby demo](https://ideone.com/81rlWD).

The `.(?=.*@)` regex matches any one char other than line break chars that is immediately preceded with any zero or more chars other than line break chars and then a `@` char.

It is unlikely there can be line break chars in the email addres, but if you ever need to support line breaks, do not forget to add `m` flag:

```rb
/.(?=.*@)/m
```

Answer (score 1):

For the pattern you can use your second approach with the negated character class

```
^[^\s@]+(?=@)
```

The pattern matches:

- `^` Start of string
- `[^\s@]+` Match 1+ times any char except @ or a whitspace char
- `(?=@)` Assert @ to the right

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/i8obNM/1/) | [Ruby demo](https://ideone.com/HtWP76)

Then you can replace with the number of chars that were matched.

```
'test@gmail.com'.gsub(/^[^\s@]+(?=@)/){|m| '*' * m.length }
```

Output

```
****@gmail.com
```

---

Another option using the `\G` anchor:

```
\G[^@](?=[^@]*@)
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/8YjqUE/1) | [Ruby demo](https://ideone.com/F6Q8fH)

The pattern matches:

- `\G` Assert the position at the end of previous match, or at the start (in this case)
- `[^@]` Match any char except `@` (add `\s` to not match space or newline)
- `(?=[^@]*@)` Assert an `@` to the right

Ruby example

```
'test@gmail.com'.gsub(/\G[^@](?=[^@]*@)/, '*')
```

Output

```
****@gmail.com
```

Answer (score 0):

try this email.replaceAll("(^[^@]{0}|(?!^)\G)[^@]", "$1*")